# How to get image from Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get an image from my Firebase Storage in Android Studio
and set the image to `ImageView`. How can I get the image from Firebase storage?

[image]

What I've tried:

```
mStorageImage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile_Images").child("UserName");
        mStorageImage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.with(AccountView.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(profileImage);
            }
        });
```

Comment: see the comment below

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am having the same issue can you please help me with it?  @stav elmashally

Answer (score 0):

You must select your image url form right side of the console inside the file location.The steps are given below

Step.1. Select Download location form your console(Its should be visible inside the file location)

2. Use Picasso or glide or whatever suits you to implement easily. Here I was implemented the glide library for display the images.

   String url="Firebase download url";

You can also use activity Instant of myFragment

```
  Glide
  .with(myFragment)
  .load(url)
  .centerCrop()
  .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
  .crossFade()
  .into(myImageView);
```