# android: I want to retrieve an image from firebase and show it in a new activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

This is how I upload the image to `Firebase` storage.
Every time the app opens, I want to fetch image from storage and display in new activity.

```
StorageReference childRef=mStorage.child(newsnow).child("image3");
UploadTask uploadTask=childRef.putFile(uri3);
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Toast.makeText(PostNews.this, "uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(PostNews.this, "no da", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving an image from firebase you have to store image URL in your Firebase database. After retrieving an image URL you can use libraries like Picasso, glide and so many others for getting an image from URL. You can prefer [this link for more description.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424024/how-to-get-image-from-firebase-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should to the trick:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_placeholder);

childRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(image);
    }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
});
```

Where `image` with `R.id.image_placeholder` is the place where you would like the image to be displayed.

Note that `childRef` is initialized in the same way that is now in your posted code.